# "deserializeJson() failed: NoMemory" Error with my NodeMcu-Mx with ESP8266

Tags: c, arduino, esp8266, json-deserialization, arduinojson

Im making a little project with my NodeMCU Mx with ESP8266, but ArduinoJson lib tells me there's an error.
I just want to fetch the data inside my json file and use the data as variable, in order to print it on a LCD display.
It was working at the beginning, but now its always makes the same error, even if i recompile and transfert it into my nodemcu.

**The code :**

```
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
String payload = "";

void setup()
{
  //CONNEXION AU WIFI
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  WiFi.begin("test", "testtest");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
    delay(100);
  }
  Serial.println("Connected !");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print("Local IP:");
  Serial.println((WiFi.localIP().toString()));
  Serial.print("Mac adress :");
  Serial.println((WiFi.macAddress().c_str()));
  Serial.print("Hostname :");
  Serial.println((WiFi.hostname()));

  //LED ALWAYS ON
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) { //Check WiFi connection status

    HTTPClient http; //Declare an object of class HTTPClient

    http.begin("http://latin-american-brea.000webhostapp.com/dan.json"); //Specify request destination
    http.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
    int httpCode = http.GET(); //Send the request

    if (httpCode > 0) { //Check the returning code

      String payload = http.getString();   //Get the request response payload
      Serial.println(payload);             //Print the response payload

      // Stream& input;

      StaticJsonDocument<96> doc;

      DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, payload);

      if (error) {
        Serial.print(F("deserializeJson() failed: "));
        Serial.println(error.f_str());
        return;
      }

      const char* fruit = doc["fruit"]; // "Apple"
      const char* sizz = doc["sizz"];   // "Large"
      const char* color = doc["color"]; // "Red"
      Serial.println(fruit);

    } else {
      Serial.println("Marche pas");
    }

    http.end(); //Close connection
  }

  Serial.println(payload);
  delay(30000); //Send a request every 30 seconds
}
```

And here's the error:

`deserializeJson() failed: NoMemory`

I don't really understand, can someone help me please?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You've specified 96 bytes as the size of the object, so the JSON you're retrieving must be larger than you're expecting.

From [Deserialization Errors](https://arduinojson.org/v6/api/misc/deserializationerror/):

```
DeserializationError::NoMemory

The JsonDocument is too small; you need to increase its capacity.
```

Copy the JSON data into your clipboard, and head on over to the [ArduinoJSON Assistant](https://arduinojson.org/v6/assistant/). Select your processor, then paste in the JSON that you're expecting. The assistant will tell you the object size you need to send into the `StaticJsonDocument<96> doc;` line.